# migrating ms access to mysql -- changing CF coding (from newbie)

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, ms-access-2003

I am migrating my coldfusion9 query code from ms access 2003 to mySql.  My MySql knowledge is limited, so this is a beginner's question :)

In my MS Access code, I used simple cfqueries... here's an example:

```
<cfquery name="catalog" datasource="mydatasource">
SELECT TableID, DateListed, FirstColor, SecondColor
FROM mytable
WHERE FirstColor='blue' OR SecondColor='blue'
ORDER BY DateListed DESC
</cfquery>
```

I understand from online reading that one needs to use cfqueryparam with mySql to protect from injected malicious code.  I'm not sure how the malicious code is injected .... as online website users don't interact with my database via forms, will I still need to use cfqueryparam?

If so, could you give me an example of an way to add cfqueryparam to the above code? -or- suggest a good, simple how-to resource for writing mySql code (in my searches online most of the coding info presupposes a higher level of knowledge than I have)

Comment: Though possible, a database driven web application that does not interact with *any* user supplied values - at all - is very unusual. Any queries that interact with user supplied values (url parameters, form fields, etcetera) are at risk.

Comment: okay, I see.  I assumed from my reading that -every- database query needed to be protected.

Comment: No, only queries that contain user supplied parameters or information can be exploited. Queries that *only* contain hard coded strings (like the one above) are safe.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to protecting from SQL injection, CFQUERYPARAM lets you use bind variables, which can give you performance gains because queries that are the same except for some variables only need to be compiled once and can be cached.

From your sample, this is how you'd used cfqueryparam:

```
<cfquery name="catalog" datasource="mydatasource">
SELECT TableID, DateListed, FirstColor, SecondColor
FROM mytable
WHERE FirstColor=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="blue">
   OR SecondColor=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="blue">
ORDER BY DateListed DESC
</cfquery>
```

That doesn't buy you much, however. The payoff is in situations like this:

```
<cfquery name="catalog" datasource="mydatasource">
SELECT TableID, DateListed, FirstColor, SecondColor
FROM mytable
WHERE FirstColor=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.color#">
   OR SecondColor=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.color#">
ORDER BY DateListed DESC
</cfquery>
```

Now whether the color is blue or red or chartreuse this query is compiled in the database and will be faster on subsequent calls. Further, a malicious user could change `form.color` to have the value of `blue';drop table users;` and you'll be protected from the SQL injection.

Comment: Al, thanks so much for your answer -- I get where you're going in the first sample code but you've lost me in the 2nd :)  I would love to optimize my database for faster caching but I don't understand your use of "form.color" -- Am I right in assuming this example assumes the initial presence of a form and that "blue" is its outputted value? If so, I'm following you :)

Comment: "form" is a variable scope created by ColdFusion automatically when an HTML form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three good reasons to use **cfqueryparam**

1) Security from injection or other bad intent from users.

2) Queries execute faster because you explicitly state their type.

3) Its just a good idea, plus similar to other language features, like

```
$unsafe_variable = $_POST["user-input"];
$safe_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($unsafe_variable);
```

We used examples like this all over of DAO objects (these are the cfcs that have the code in them that speak to the database)

```
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value=#arguments.assessmentID# />
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" value='%#arguments.searchString#%' />
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_DATE" value=#arguments.assessmentDate# />
```

Where the #arguments.varname# was passed into the method containing the SQL.